# Herencia agregar valores de padre a hijo C#

Tags: c#, herencia

Tengo un Objeto `Parent` y un Objeto `Child:Parent`

Existe alguna manera de crear el objeto `Parent` y asignárselo al Hijo?

```
Parent padre = new Parent();
 // Proceso de llenado de Parent
...
//
Child hijo = padre;
```

Comment: Y para qué querrías hacer eso, no sería mejor instanciarlo en otra variable?

Comment: lo que pasa es que tengo 2 Clases Hijas que heredan del mismo Padre y Tengo una funcion que llena  todo lo que tiene la Clase Padre.

Es por eso que quiero llamar esa funcion y segun necesite la Hijo1 o Hijo2 llenarla con la info del Parent

Comment: Usa as o casting

Comment: Le intente no genero errores, pero cuando veo el resultado al igualar se encuentra en Null,

Hize algo como esto.
Child hijo = padre as Child;